# iOS - Stop a repeating UIAnimation?

Tags: ios, uianimation

I have an animation that needs to be repeated until I decided to stop it.

How can I stop in animation after a button click?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat) animations:^{

        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(5));
        self.transform = transform;

    }  completion:^(BOOL finished){

    }];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have a handler to repeat UIView animateWithDuration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766955/how-to-have-a-handler-to-repeat-uiview-animatewithduration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can make use of CABasicAnimation instead.

```
    CABasicAnimation *appDeleteShakeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
appDeleteShakeAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
appDeleteShakeAnimation.repeatDuration = HUGE_VALF;
appDeleteShakeAnimation.duration = 0.2;
appDeleteShakeAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-degreeToRadian(5)];
appDeleteShakeAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:degreeToRadian(5)];
[self.layer addAnimation:appDeleteShakeAnimation forKey:@"appDeleteShakeAnimation"];
```

Then when u want to stop it you can just call

```
[self.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"appDeleteShakeAnimation"];
```

Answer (score 13):

You have to add one other option `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` ...

You should try this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^
{
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 200, 200);
} completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    if(! finished) return;
}];
```

And to stop the animation use this:

```
[view.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

Comment: Good response on the concrete question, without suggesting another approach to animate view.  Good job.